# Interview: How to ensure that a thread runs after another?

Tags: java, multithreading

There are thread `T1`, `T2` and `T3`, how can we ensure that thread `T2` run after `T1` and thread `T3` run after `T2`?

This question was asked in my interview. I didn't answer. Please explain in detail.

Comment: Answer: Quit trying to use separate threads to do what are obviously sequential tasks.  The point of threads is to be able to conceptually do two things at once.  If one thread has to finish before another starts, then they have no business being separate threads; making them such and then attempting to force sequence on them gets you nothing but increased complexity.

Answer (score 30):

This would be the simplest, dumbest approach:

```
final Thread t1 = new Thread(new T1()); // assume T1 is a Runnable
t1.start();
t1.join();
final Thread t2 = new Thread(new T2());
t2.start();
t2.join();
final Thread t3 = new Thread(new T3());
t3.start();
t3.join();
```

Comment: Come on - and you complain about my running my runnables sequentially! You could at least make them somewhat parallel!

Comment: Unless you interpret "T1 runs after T2" as "T1 starts after T2 has ended".

Comment: @assylias That's exactly how I interpret it. Your solution is a true real-world win for this use case, as everyone will agree, but this goes towards satisfying the requirements as stated.

Comment: @assylias I see now what you meant, I didn't realize that would also be a way to interpret the words of the question: ensuring that T2 starts running after T1 has started running. That would be a job for a `Phaser`.

Comment: Then it seems we can agree that the question is not very clear as it is. I have never done an IT interview (not being a programmer), but it seems they often come up with weird, imprecise questions with little practical use! Whatever...

Comment: @Assylias - exactly.  It's an annoying question about a silly scenario that can be easily misinterpreted.  Even if you enforce the run order by creating the later threads in the run() method of earlier threads, the scheduler could just decide to change the thread states at any time because of some unrelated hardware interrupt has caused a scheduler run.

Comment: @assylias is not a professional?  Why not?  Hey Assylias - you have a huge private income/wealth and do not need to work?  <g>

Answer (score 6):

The obvious, and simplest, way has already been posted by @Assylias - have T1 run method create/start T2 and T2 run method create/start T3.

It is, IMHO, verging on pointless, but it could be done.

Solutions using Join() do not answer the question - they ensure that the termination of the threads is ordered, not the running of them.  If the interviewr does not get that, you need to find another job anyway.

In an interview, my answer would be 'For ***** sake why?  Threads are ususally used to avoid exactly what you are asking!'.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it would be something like the following.  It's complex though.  You might want to use the [`java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) class for this.

Each thread when it finishes sets the boolean value and notifies the next thread to continue.  Even though it is an `AtomicBoolean` class, we need the `synchronized` so we can `wait()` and `notify()` on it.

It would be cleaner to pass in the lock objects or maybe have a `begin()` method on `T2` and `T3` so we can hide the locks inside of those objects.

```
final Object lock2 = new Object();
final Object lock3 = new Object();
boolean ready2;
boolean ready3;
...
public T1 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        ...
        synchronized (lock2) {
            // notify the T2 class that it should start
            ready2 = true;
            lock2.notify();
        }
    }
}
...

public T2 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // the while loop takes care of errant signals
        synchronized (lock2) {
            while (!ready2) {
                lock2.wait();
            }
        }
        ...
        // notify the T3 class that it should start
        synchronized (lock3) {
            ready3 = true;
            lock3.notify();
        }
    }
}
...
public T3 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // the while loop takes care of errant signals
        synchronized (lock3) {
            while (!ready3) {
                lock3.wait();
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in `run()` method of `T2` you trying to say `synchronized (lock2) {` instead of `synchronized (lock3) {`

Comment: @Gray, Is there an advantage of using `AtomicBoolean` instead of `Boolean` in this case?

Comment: You can't synchronize on a `Boolean` @John.  That's a FAQ.  You could have a `final Object lock` and a `boolean` but there's not much point.  Also, `AtomicBoolean` allows you to test locks without having to synchronize.

Comment: @Gray: Can we not use an (Atomic)Integer so that multiple boolean lock variables are not required? Just  check for <= 1 or 2 etc?

Comment: You could do that @Danyal although I'm not sure it would save you much.   I've changed my answer a bit because the old one had some race conditions.

Answer (score 4):

There are thread T1, T2 and T3, how can we ensure that thread T2 run 
after T1 and thread T3 run after T2?
OR
There are three threads T1, T2 and T3? How do you ensure sequence T1, T2, T3 in Java?
The question basically is T3 should finish first , T2 second and T1 last.
We can use use join() method of thread class. 
To ensure three threads execute you need to start the last one first e.g. T3 and then call join methods in reverse order e.g. T3 calls T2.join, 
 and T2 calls T1.join. In this way, T1 will finish first and T3 will finish last.

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("start 1");
                System.out.println("end 1");
            }//run
        });

        final Thread t2  = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(" start 2 ");
                try {
                    t1.join(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(" end 2");
            }
        }) ;

        final Thread t3 = new Thread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(" start 3 ");

                try {
                    t2.join(4000);
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(" end  3 ");
            }
        });
       // we are reversing the order of the start() method
        t3.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.start();


    }
}
```

From the output, You can see that threads have started in different order as you don't know which thread will get CPU. Its the decision of the Thread Scheduler, so we cannot do anything. But, you can see that threads are finished in correct order i.e.  T1 then T2  and then T3.

There is another way of doing it. The pseudo code is :

```
t1.start();

    t1.join(); // signals t2 to wait

    if( !t1.isAlive()) {
        t2.start();// if t1 is finished then t2 will start
    }

    t2.join();//signals t3 to wait

    if (!t2.isAlive()) {
        t3.start(); 
    }
```

Let's take a full program:

```
 public class Tic implements Runnable{
   public void run() {
       try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                  System.out.println("tic");
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
   }
}

public class Tac implements Runnable{
       public void run() {
           try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                      System.out.println("tac");
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
       }
    }
public class Toe implements Runnable{
       public  void run() {
           try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                      System.out.println("toe");
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
       }
    }

public class RunThreads1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Tic tic = new Tic();
        Tac tac = new Tac();
        Toe toe = new Toe();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(tic);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(tac);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(toe);
        t1.start();

        t1.join(); // signals t2 to wait

        if( !t1.isAlive()) {
            t2.start();// if t1 is finished then t2 will start
        }

        t2.join();//signals t3 to wait

        if (!t2.isAlive()) {
            t3.start(); 
        }

    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The output is : 
tic
tic
tac
tac
toe
toe

Answer (score 3):

Threads are also runnables. You can simply run them sequentially:

```
t1.run();
t2.run();
t3.run();
```

This has obviously little interest.

Assuming they want the threads to run in parallel, one solution would be to have each thread start the next one, since [the JMM guarantees that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.

Comment: Then they aren't "Threads".  They are just objects.  I doubt that would be a good answer to an interview question.

Comment: @Gray I can't disagree with the last part of your comment.

Comment: Although the answer is correct, i would not say this is what they expect you to do, but still correct +1 from me :)

Comment: @fmucar True - I'm just pointing out that the question as it is is not well formulated.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It seems my sense of humour does not get unanimous approval (unsurprisingly: I talk to British people all day long) - I'll delete a bit later ;-)

Comment: I see---yes, it's a little too subtle for this context :)

Comment: If the question is written as above, i would say maybe this is the answer they are expecting as it is not wrong.

Comment: @fmucar I have added an alternative answer to satisfy the commenters.

Comment: sorry mate, i can only upvote once although i wanna do it twice. :)

Comment: +1 this is exactly what i would have done. Now what the question actually tries to test maybe something different, but programmers (and persons interviewing them) should be specific.

Comment: I still think that a solution with a `static Phaser` would beat this one in simplicity. I'd code it in my answer, but on my Mac I still don't get Java 7... I may try, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

At the start of each thread (except t1), make it call join() on it's predecessor.  Using executors (instead of threads directly) is another option.  One could also look at using semaphores - T1 should release the permit upon completion, T2 should try to acquire two permits, and release them when done, T3 should try to acquire three permits & so on.  Using join or executors would be the preferred route.

Answer (score 3):

Guess what interviewer asking was three threads do the work in sequence.For example if one thread prints 1,4,5...second 2,5,8 and thirds 3,6,9 etc..ur output should be 1,2,3,4,5.....
Ist thread prints 1 and gives chance to 2nd thread to print 2..etc.,

I tried it using cyclebarriers.As soon as 'one' prints 1it gives chance to two as it calls cb.wait,when two runs it will in turn call three in similar fashion and it will continue.Let me know if thr are any bugs in the code

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

class one implements Runnable{
    CyclicBarrier cb;
    one(CyclicBarrier cb){this.cb=cb;}
    public void run(){
        int i=1;
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                cb.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i=i+3;
        }
    }

}
class two implements Runnable{
    CyclicBarrier cb;
    int i=2;
    two(CyclicBarrier cb){this.cb=cb;}
    public void run(){


        System.out.println(i);
        try {
            cb.await();
            i=i+3;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public class oneTwoThree {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Runnable threePrinter = new Runnable() {
            int i=3;
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(i);
                i=i+3;
            }
        };


        CyclicBarrier bar2 =new CyclicBarrier(1,threePrinter);//, barrier1Action);
        two twoPrinter  =new two(bar2);
        CyclicBarrier bar1 =new CyclicBarrier(1,twoPrinter);

        Thread onePrinter=new Thread(new one(bar1));
        onePrinter.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: The exact same question was asked to me in an interview today. Couldn't answer it. I was searching for the answer of this question, finally landed in your response here. It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried in a much simpler way.. using a waits and notifies.(as opposed to cyclic barrier approach in my prev post).

It uses a 'State' class... which gets three states:1,2,3.(default 3).
 When it is at 3, it triggers t1, at 1 will trigger t2, at 2 will trigger t3 and so on.

Classes:
State// int i=3
T1// prints 1,4,7...
T2// Prints 2,5,8
T3//Prints 3,6,9 etc.,

Please let me know your views or if any issues in the code. Thanks.

Here is the code.:

```
public class State {

    private int state ;

    public State() {
        this.state =3;
    }

    public synchronized int getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public synchronized void setState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }


}


public class T1 implements Runnable {

    State s;
    public T1(State s) {
        this.s =s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i =1;

        while(i<50)
        {
            //System.out.println("s in t1 "+ s.getState());

            while(s.getState() != 3)
            {

                synchronized(s)
                {
                    try {
                        s.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }

            synchronized(s)
            {
                //if(s.getState() ==3)

                if(s.getState()==3)
                System.out.println("t1 "+i);
                s.setState(1);
                i = i +3 ;
                s.notifyAll();


            }

        }

    }

}




public class T2 implements Runnable {

    State s;
    public T2(State s) {
        this.s =s;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        int i =2;

        while(i<50)
        {

            while(s.getState() != 1)
            {

                synchronized(s)
                {
                    try {
                        s.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }

            synchronized(s)
            {
                //if(s.getState() ==3)

                if(s.getState()==1)
                System.out.println("t2 "+i);
                s.setState(2);
                i = i +3 ;
                s.notifyAll();

            }

        }




    }


}



public class T3 implements Runnable {

    State s;
    public T3(State s) {
        this.s =s;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        int i =3;

        while(i<50)
        {

            while(s.getState() != 2)
            {
                synchronized(s)
                {
                    try {
                        s.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }

            synchronized(s)
            {

                if(s.getState()==2)
                System.out.println("t3 "+i);
                i = i +3 ;
                s.setState(3);
                s.notifyAll();
            }

        }



    }}





    public class T1t2t3 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            State s = new State();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new T1(s));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new T2(s));
            Thread t3 = new Thread(new T3(s));

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t3.start();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can we ensure that thread T2 run after T1 and thread T3 run after T2?

```
NOTE: Assuming that it is not about scheduling the threads in the required order
```

We could use the [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) Interface.
We'll need two conditions bound to a single [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html): **condition1** to coordinate T1 and T2, **condition2** to coordinate T2 and T3.
Pass **condition1** to T1 and T2, **condition2** to T2 and T3.
So, we would have T2 *await* on **condition1** in it's run method, which will be  *signalled* by T1 (from T1's run method, after T1 starts/finishes its task).
 Similarly have T3 *await* on **condition2** in it's run method, which will be *signalled* by T2 (from T2's run method, after it starts/finishes it's task).

Answer (score 0):

Create a priority queue with each tread in the other they are created. 
You can then apply `Thread.join` after it completes, remove that thread from the priority queue, and then execute the first element of the queue again.
Pseudocode:

```
   pthread [3] my_threads
    my_queue
    for t in pthreads:
         my_queue.queue(t)

   while !my_queue.empty()
      pop the head of the queue
      wait until it complets
      thread.join()
```

implementation is left as exercise, so next time you get it right!

Answer (score 0):

Use the thread isAlive method before starting the thread T2 and T3.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new T1()); 
Thread t2 = new Thread(new T2()); 
Thread t3 = new Thread(new T3()); 
t1.start();

if(t1.isAlive()){   

    t2.start();

}

if(t2.isAlive()){

    t3.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code while using that you can run n number of thread in that manner.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class CyclicExecutionOfThreads {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int totalNumOfThreads = 10;
        PrintJob printJob = new PrintJob(totalNumOfThreads);

        /*
        MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable(printJob, 1);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable);

        MyRunnable runnable2 = new MyRunnable(printJob, 2);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable2);

        MyRunnable runnable3 = new MyRunnable(printJob, 3);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(runnable3);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        */

        //OR

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors
                .newFixedThreadPool(totalNumOfThreads);
        Set<Runnable> runnables = new HashSet<Runnable>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalNumOfThreads; i++) {
            MyRunnable command = new MyRunnable(printJob, i);
            runnables.add(command);
            executorService.execute(command);
        }

        executorService.shutdown();

    }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    PrintJob printJob;
    int threadNum;

    public MyRunnable(PrintJob job, int threadNum) {
        this.printJob = job;
        this.threadNum = threadNum;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (printJob) {
                if (threadNum == printJob.counter) {
                    printJob.printStuff();

                    if (printJob.counter != printJob.totalNumOfThreads) {
                        printJob.counter++;
                    } else {

                        System.out.println();
                        // reset the counter
                        printJob.resetCounter();

                    }

                    printJob.notifyAll();

                } else {
                    try {
                        printJob.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

}

class PrintJob {
    int counter = 1;
    int totalNumOfThreads;

    PrintJob(int totalNumOfThreads) {
        this.totalNumOfThreads = totalNumOfThreads;
    }

    public void printStuff() {
        System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " is printing");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void resetCounter() {
        this.counter = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package thread;

class SyncPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SyncPrinterAction printAction1 = new SyncPrinterAction(new int[]{1,5,9,13}, true);
        SyncPrinterAction printAction2 = new SyncPrinterAction(new int[]{2,6,10,14}, true);
        SyncPrinterAction printAction3 = new SyncPrinterAction(new int[]{3,7,11,15}, true);
        SyncPrinterAction printAction4 = new SyncPrinterAction(new int[]{4,8,12,16}, false);

    printAction1.setDependentAction(printAction4);
    printAction2.setDependentAction(printAction1);
    printAction3.setDependentAction(printAction2);
    printAction4.setDependentAction(printAction3);

    new Thread(printAction1, "T1").start();;        
    new Thread(printAction2, "T2").start();
    new Thread(printAction3, "T3").start();     
    new Thread(printAction4, "T4").start();



}
}

class SyncPrinterAction implements Runnable {

private volatile boolean dependent;
private SyncPrinterAction dependentAction;
int[] data;

public void setDependentAction(SyncPrinterAction dependentAction){
    this.dependentAction = dependentAction;

}

public SyncPrinterAction( int[] data, boolean dependent) {
    this.data = data;
    this.dependent = dependent;
}

public SyncPrinterAction( int[] data, SyncPrinterAction dependentAction, boolean dependent) {
    this.dependentAction = dependentAction;
    this.data = data;
    this.dependent = dependent;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {

        for (int value : data) {

            try {
                while(dependentAction.isDependent())
                    //System.out.println("\t\t"+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " :: Waithing for dependent action to complete");
                wait(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            dependentAction.setDependent(true);

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " :: " +value);
            dependent = false;
        }

    }

}

private void setDependent(boolean dependent) {
    this.dependent = dependent;

}

private boolean isDependent() {
    return dependent;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concurrent package has better classes to use the shared object.
One of the way is like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    ThreadId threadId = new RunInSequence.ThreadId();
    threadId.setId(1);
    Thread t1 = setThread("thread1",lock, condition, 1, 2, threadId);
    Thread t2 = setThread("thread2",lock, condition, 2, 3, threadId);
    Thread t3 = setThread("thread3",lock, condition, 3, 1, threadId);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

}

private static class ThreadId {
    private int id;

    public ThreadId() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

private static Thread setThread(final String name,final Lock lock, final Condition condition, int actualThreadId, int nextThreadId,
        ThreadId threadId) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    while (threadId.getId() != actualThreadId) {
                        try {
                            condition.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(name+"prints: " + actualThreadId);
                    threadId.setId(nextThreadId);
                    condition.signalAll();
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return thread;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

class Worker implements Runnable {

  BlockingQueue<Integer> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
  Worker next = null; // next worker in the chain

  public void setNext(Worker t) {
    this.next = t;
  }

  public void accept(int i) {
    q.add(i);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      int i;
      try {
        i = q.take(); // this blocks the queue to fill-up
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + i);
        if (next != null) {
          next.accept(i + 1); // Pass the next number to the next worker
        }
        Thread.sleep(500); // Just sleep to notice the printing.
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}

public class PrintNumbersSequentially {
  public static void main(String[] as) {

    Worker w1 = new Worker();
    Worker w2 = new Worker();
    Worker w3 = new Worker();

    w1.setNext(w2);
    w2.setNext(w3);
    w3.setNext(w1);

    new Thread(w1, "Thread-1: ").start();
    new Thread(w2, "Thread-2: ").start();
    new Thread(w3, "Thread-3: ").start();

    //Till here all the threads have started, but no action takes place as the queue is not filled for any worker. So Just filling up one worker.
    w1.accept(100);
  }
}
```

I think this could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

**By using join you can ensure running of a thread one after another.**

```
class MyTestThread implements Runnable{

    public void run() {
    System.out.println("==MyTestThread : START : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " :i = "+i);
    }
    System.out.println("==MyTestThread : END : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}
public class ThreadJoinTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyTestThread(), "t1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new MyTestThread(), "t2");

        thread1.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.start();
        thread2.join();

        System.out.println("====All threads execution===completed");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package io.hariom.threading;
```

//You have three threads T1, T2, and T3, How do you ensure that they finish in order T1, T2, T3 ?

public class ThreadTest1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(null));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(thread1));
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(thread2));
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();

}
```

}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
Thread t;

```
MyRunnable(Thread t) {
    this.t = t;

}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (t != null) {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " starts");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ends");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to the problem using **CountDownLatch** for signalling .

T1 thread after doing its job signal to T2 and T2 to T3.

```
public class T1T2T3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    CountDownLatch c1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
    CountDownLatch c2 = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Thread T1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("T1");
        c1.countDown();
      }
    });
    Thread T2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //should listen to something from T1
        try {
          c1.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("T2");
        c2.countDown();
      }
    });
    Thread T3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          c2.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("T3");
      }
    });

    T1.start();
    T3.start();
    T2.start();
  }
}
```